# Discord c# - Check number of parameters in a command

Tags: c#, bots, discord

With my discord bot in c#, i tried to send an help message of command if there is 0 paramater sent.
**Command:** *!onserver* >> Send help message

Thank you for your help.

```
commands.CreateCommand("onserver")
 .Parameter("server", ParameterType.Required)
 .Hide()
 .Do(async (e) =>
 {
    int server = Convert.ToInt32(e.GetArg("server"));
    if (e.GetArg("server").Length == 0) //Show command help
     {
         await e.Channel.SendMessage("Help message blablabla");
     } 
     if (server > 0)
     {
         await e.Channel.SendMessage($"Utilisateur lanceur: {e.Message.User}");
         await e.Channel.SendMessage($"Serveur choisi: {server}");
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

try:
   `int server = Convert.ToInt32(e.Args[0]);`